# Can you force http/1.1 with Google HTTPS load balancers?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a Google HTTPS load balancer that automatically negotiates http/1.1 or http/2 depending on the client. I'm experiencing some strange issues with http/2 and would like to temporarily disable http/2 and force all clients to use http/1.1. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible. Have a look at the documentation [External HTTP(S) Load Balancing overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) in section [Client communications with the load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#client_communications_with_the_load_balancer):

> - Clients can communicate with the load balancer by using the HTTP 1.1 or HTTP/2 protocol.
> - When HTTPS is used, modern clients default to HTTP/2. This is controlled on the client, not on the HTTPS load balancer.
> - **You cannot disable HTTP/2 by making a configuration change on the load balancer**. However, you can configure some clients to use HTTP
>     1.1 instead of HTTP/2. For example, with `curl`, use the `--http1.1` parameter.
> - HTTPS load balancers do not support client certificate-based authentication, also known as mutual TLS authentication.